# How to use 'ref' in Nuxt.js 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

in Following, What i want is, when i change status code using Radio button to get data according to status like "Active, Draft or Trash" from API. CONST params should update.

but on changing the radio input, params is not getting updated. it always print

```
api_key=**********&language=en-US&deletedStatus=false&byCity=&byCountry=&page=1&ActiveStatus=true&limit=20
```

but in vue dev tools, i can see these individual datas are updated except params.

```html
<template>
          <div
           v-for="(status, index) in StatusOptions"
           :key="index"
           class="field-radiobutton ttc-pr-2"
           >
              <RadioButton
               :id="status.value"
               name="status"
               :value="status.value"
               @change="ChangeState(status.value)"
               />
              <label>{{ status.name }}</label>
           </div>
        </template>
            
        <script setup>
            import { ref, reactive } from "vue";
            const { apiUrl } = useRuntimeConfig();
            const router = useRouter();
            const route = useRoute();
            
            const deletedStatus = ref(false);
            const byCity = ref("");
            const byCountry = ref("");
            const page = ref(1);
            const ActiveStatus = ref(true);
            const limit = ref(20);
            
            const StatusOptions = ref([
              { name: "Active", value: "Active" },
              { name: "Draft", value: "Draft" },
              { name: "Trash", value: "Trash" },
            ]);
            
            const ChangeState = (state) => {
              if (state == `Active`) {
                deletedStatus.value = false;
                ActiveStatus.value = true;
              }
              if (state == `Draft`) {
                ActiveStatus.value = false;
              }
              if (state == `Trash`) {
                ActiveStatus.value = false;
                deletedStatus.value = true;
              }
              console.log(params.value)
              FetchTours();
            };
            
            
            const params = ref(
              [
                "api_key=****************",
                "language=en-US",
                `deletedStatus=${deletedStatus.value}`,
                `byCity=${byCity.value}`,
                `byCountry=${byCountry.value}`,
                `page=${page.value}`,
                `ActiveStatus=${ActiveStatus.value}`,
                `limit=${limit.value}`,
              ].join("&")
            );
            
            const FetchTours = async () => {
              const { data } = await useFetch(`${apiUrl}/tours/gettours?${params.value}`, {
                key: "someKey",
                initialCache: false,
              });
              AllTours.value = data.value;
            };
            </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a computed value. The refs is oly initiated with the base information. Passing `.value` to your `params` variable only assigns the value, not the reference.

The usage of `computed` will track the dependencies of this variable, and will update accordingly when one of the dependencies changes.

```ts
const params = computed(() => [
    "api_key=****************",
    "language=en-US",
    `deletedStatus=${deletedStatus.value}`,
    `byCity=${byCity.value}`,
    `byCountry=${byCountry.value}`,
    `page=${page.value}`,
    `ActiveStatus=${ActiveStatus.value}`,
    `limit=${limit.value}`,
  ].join("&")
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the support ! i now learn using computed in NuxtJs3.